# Form validation and Ajax - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have form that has to be validated before submitting and notification should be shown with error without reloading the page.

Form code:

```
<button name="save" type="submit" form="product_form">Save</button>             
    <div>
        <form id="product_form" method="POST"">
            <label for="sku">SKU: </label>
            <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" required><br>
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required><br>
            <label for="price">Price: </label>
            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" required><br>    
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="validaton"></div>
```

I did validation in another `validateData.php` :

```
    <?php
    
    include __DIR__ . "/connectQuery.php";
    $sku=$_POST["sku"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
    
    $data = $query->getAllProducts();
    $objectMap = new ObjectMap($data);
    $productsArray = $objectMap->getAllProducts();
    $skuError="";
    $priceError="";
    $dataError="";
    // SKU validation 
    foreach($productsArray as $product)
    {
        if($product->getSku()==$sku)
        {
           $skuError="Your SKU is not unique!";
        }
    
    }
    echo $skuError;
    
    //Price validation
    if (!is_numeric($price))
    {
        $priceError = "Please enter valid data for price!";
    }
    echo $priceError;

//if there is no error 
if($priceError!="" && $skuError !="")
{

 header("Location: index.php");
}
```

So, my idea was to when I submit form, it calls this `validateData.php`, checks value, if there is  error, echoes the error, and if not then redirect to `index.php` and it works, but I can't show those error messages without reloading page, so I guess I need to use ajax. I tried to write it:

```
function validateData(form){
 var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
        if(this.status==200 && this.readyState==4)
        {
           document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
        }

    }
  
    xhr.open("POST","/partial/validateData.php");
    xhr.send();

  }
```

So, my questions are:

- Do I use in html form `onsubmit="validateData(this)"` to reach ajax?
- How to stop form from reloading page after submit? I found some solutions on net, but they are all in JQuery and I need Vanilla JS.
- How to  reach those input values from `form` in ajax, so I can send them via `xhr.open("POST");`

If there is easier way to do, I am open to listen, as I said, I need to check data, and if it is not valid show errors without reloading page. I am sorry for long post and questions, I am new to this concept.

Comment: maybe add `return false;` after `xhr.send()`

Comment: Also sort out the HTML, closing a DIV inside a form that was opened outside the form can cause its own issues

Comment: @johnSmith it is working, but now I have another problem. If something is wrong, it print values in div `validation`. But if form is valid, it opens new page in that div. I know why is that, because of: `document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = this.responseText; ` but how to change it so if there is error it print error in div `validation` but if everything is fine it open new page in full screen, as a new page, and not in that div

Comment: @Raskoljnikovic well that is because if everything is fine server redirects to `Location: index.php` so your ajax-response is the html of the startpage. So if you do `.innerHTML = this.responseText; ` it will render the complete startpage into that div. You should rather return a "success" message or sth. like that and in your ajax-response handler you do the redirect on success with js, sth. like `window.location.href = "/index.php";` just like Mohammed Khurram did in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
<?php
    
    include __DIR__ . "/connectQuery.php";
    $sku=$_POST["sku"];
    $name=$_POST["name"];
    $price=$_POST["price"];
    
    $data = $query->getAllProducts();
    $objectMap = new ObjectMap($data);
    $productsArray = $objectMap->getAllProducts();
    $skuError="";
    $priceError="";
    $dataError="";
    // SKU validation 
    foreach($productsArray as $product)
    {
        if($product->getSku()==$sku)
        {
           $skuError="Your SKU is not unique!";
        }
    
    }
    echo $skuError;
    
    //Price validation
    if (!is_numeric($price))
    {
        $priceError = "Please enter valid data for price!";
    }
    echo $priceError;

//if there is no error 
if($priceError!="" && $skuError !="")
{
 echo "noerror";
 //header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Javascript

```
function validateData(form){
 var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
        if(this.status==200 && this.readyState==4)
        {
           if(this.responseText === 'noerror') location.replace("index.php");
           else document.getElementById("validation").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
        }

    }
  
    xhr.open("POST","/partial/validateData.php");
    xhr.send();

  }
```

For form getting submitted, you can use `type='button'` instead of `type='submit'` easy fix.

For any queries comment down.

Comment: This is what I needed. Just I could not use `if(this.responseText === 'noerror')`  for some reason it was never true,  so I used `if(!this.responseText.localeCompare("noerror"))`